# CakePHP 2.x virtual host file for Apache2

Tags: php, cakephp, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

Has anybody got a good example of a production server / test server virtual host file for CakePHP 2.x and Apache2?

I had hoped it would have been covered in the Cake docs, but the closest I could find was this; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/